# Run the Single User mode with rEFIt installed

Tags: efi

I recently installed rEFIt boot for a small linux partition. I then tried to boot up into single user mode by hitting {COMMAND + S}, but rEFIts own terminal came up.

Is there any way to still get into single user mode while rEFIt boot is installed?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, have to press **F2** when I am in the rEFIt menu, and then select **Single USER mode**